# firebird index maintence: slows after reboot

Tags: indexing, firebird

I have some table in a database with more than 40 M record.
On computer reboot, on the first `set statistics index id` (for each index), I spend about a minute.

After first time the command coast only few ms.
On service reboot or program reboot I do not have this problem: I see this behaviour only on reboot and only the first time execution of index recalculation.

```
Set statistics index index_dummy;
```

So the question is:
How avoid this 'feature'?

Comment: As I also mention in my answer, find out **why** you are doing it after every reboot. Doing it "just because" is a sign of cargo-cult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't do `set statistics` after every reboot (or consider not rebooting so often that this delay of one minute becomes noticeable).

The index statistics Firebird calculates are relatively simple, so unless your data volume (number of rows) regularly changes orders of magnitude, or selectivity ('uniqueness' of index values) varies wildly between "very unique" and "very identical", recalculating will probably have no measurable effect on the optimizer, because the statistics calculated will only vary a little bit, which makes the value of having recalculated it slim to none.

The reason it takes long the first time after reboot, is probably because your database (or at least the index pages) can fit fully into the filesystem cache. Doing `set statistics` for all indexes immediately after boot will start reading all index pages into the cache.

Subsequent re-executions of `set statistics` will then be able to read the pages from cache, which avoids hitting the disk, which makes it significantly faster.

Be aware, it is entirely possible that this use of `set statistics` is actually intentional and used (abused) to prime the filesystem cache. This way, after an initial performance hit on start up, all other users of the database get the benefits of having all indexes already loaded into the filesystem cache.

If this is the operational procedure in your company, you may want to ask around **why** you need to do `set statistics` after every reboot (because really: apart from this trick, there is no need to regularly do this if volume and uniqueness of index values are relatively stable).

Comment: My system have to support 2K insert a minute. I noticed that after 6M of record all the querry slowed down.

Comment: My system have to support 2K insert a minute.                                    I noticed that after 6M insert all the querry slowed down (simple querry as 'select first 10 * from table order by primaryKey desc;'), so for this reason I'm forcing set statistics. 
if there are better ways to do it I will be very happy to receive your advice.

Comment: @CristianLorenzin Consider posting to the firebird-support list instead. I think you have convinced yourself that `set statistics` fixes your problem, while it probably only fixed your problem initially after the growth from 0 to a few million record (when the change in statistics was important for the optimizer to make the right choice), and now it is just cargo-cult. It is also possible that you don't correctly garbage collect the database (which can be as simple as doing a daily backup). However, Stack Overflow is not a suitable venue for discussing/troubleshooting.

Comment: I realize. Thank you so much for helping me to frame the problem.